# How to reference assets between multiple asset bundle in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, assetbundle, addressable

I am trying to figure out how to properly package my bundles. My goal is to try and avoid necessary duplication of assets and cut down on download time of the assets by having smaller bundles. The current problem is that I am not sure how would bundle A reference assets from bundle B that it is depended on.
Example in my case are lets say fonts. I have  bundle A and B that should use fonts from Fonts bundle. I was under impression that unity would figure this referencing out on its own if I just load them all but that doesn't seem to be the case.
How would I make this work do I need to maybe use addressables (I never used them so I am not sure if this could be one of use case for them)?

Comment: I think you're right that this is one of the problems addressables are meant to help solve. I'd recommend giving them a try while you wait for answers here — you might find the solution first.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html) that tells you how to load assets from bundles, or the [supplementary documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Dependencies.html) on dependencies? What questions do you have that aren't answered by these documentation pages?

Comment: I did and for the smaller case I found out that splitting assets works like in example. I am not sure why it doesn't work for me at a larger scale maybe my bundle isn't right or load order I am still doing some experiments I will update the question when I have more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading bundle with common assets before main asset bundle seams to work on smaller scale so it was probably issue with my loading method. One thing I did noticed is that Unity didn't pull all my shader assets for the text when I moved them in a separate bundle so that caused missing reference. So make sure you have them in your bundle if you are experiencing font issues.